# start date is first day of month, end date is subsequent month first day Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, date

I'm looking to iterate through a date range where start_date and end_date increment on a monthly basis with each iteration starting at the beginning of the month.

First iteration example:

```
start_date = '2020-01-01'
end_date = '2020-02-01'
```

The second iteration of the loop should look like:

```
start_date = '2020-02-01'
end_date = '2020-03-01'
```

what I've tried:

```
for x in range(20):
    start_date = pd.Timestamp('2020-01-01') + pd.offsets.MonthBegin(n=1)
    end_date = start_date + pd.offsets.MonthBegin(n=1)
```

The issue I am having is that on the next iteration I am not incrementing to the next month. it stays on the current month. Is there a way to increment to the next month?

Comment: replace `n` by `x` in the start_date and by `x+1` in the end_date ? you should probably collect the dates in a list if you want to keep track of them.

Comment: This actually did the trick. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
start_date = pd.to_datetime('2020-02-01')
end_date = pd.to_datetime('2020-03-01')
for x in range(20):
     
    print(start_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
    print(end_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
    # do the work here...


    # then increment the dates for the next iteration
    start_date = start_date + pd.offsets.MonthBegin(n=1)
    end_date = start_date + pd.offsets.MonthBegin(n=1)
```

seems to do the job

Comment: the answer above did the trick but this does as well. ty!